# My bike makes a constant squeak noise

Tags: compact-crankset

I have a Trek Ermonda AL 4 and whenever I pedal forward, I hear a loud and irritating squeaking noise from the middle center of the bike. If I pedal softly I don't hear the noise as much and if I pedal super hard I also dont hear the noise as much. Its just mainly whenever I'm riding at a decent pace. I just replaced the cassette and my derailleur.
Crank
Shimano Tiagra, 50/34 (compact)

Bottom bracket
Press Fit BB86.5

Comment: There can be a lot of things causing this - pedals, seatpost, saddle, even stem or a handlebars. Try to reproduce the noise while standing up on pedals or while not holding the handlebars. This may help to eliminate some possible reasons

Comment: I've generally found this to be caused by the bottom bracket or one of the pedals.

Comment: Is the squeaking in time with the pedals or the wheels and does it do it when you're just coasting and not pedalling, and what about if you stand up to pedal?

Comment: This happens when I'm standing and sitting on the pedals and does not happen when coasting

Comment: @ConnorCrafter - You skipped over part user's question:  Does the squeak beat in time with the pedal crank or with the wheels (or seemingly independent of both)?

Comment: They only squeak when pedal crank

Answer (score 4):

Bicycle drivetrains can make all kinds of squeaking or creaking noises and it's not obvious where exactly the noise is coming from. You have to use a process of elimination to track them down.

Can you replicate the noise with the back wheel off the ground and turning the pedals by hand. If so is the sound coming from the front crank area or the rear derailleur area?

Does the noise continue when you stop pedaling? If not turn your attention to the rear wheel.

My first guess is that your chain is not lubricated properly. Dry chains tend to squeak. Bad rear derailleur indexing, chain rub on front derailleur tend to clatter or rattle. Bottom brackets tend to creak more when applying high torque through the pedals.

Another prime suspect would be the rear derailleur jockey wheels, but you said you just replaced the derailleur.

Check the crank is spinning freely and there is no play in the bearings. This is easier if you open the front derailleur cage and pop the chain off the chainrings.

Also check both the pedals are turning freely and there is no play in the bearings. Try unclipping one foot at a time while riding. If the squeak disappears when you unclip a foot it's that pedal.

Comment: If a squeak is in time with wheel rotations then it's very unlikely to be due to the BB.  And, likewise, if the squeak is in time with the crank it's very unlikely to be due to the wheels.

Comment: ... and if the squeak is periodic with a longer time constant than the pedaling, it's most likely the chain. Really: Pay attention to the repetition frequency of any drive-train noise, and you already have the source narrowed down quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to use process of elimination.
1. Lube seat/seat post, saddle rails
2. Check pedal and cleat interface.  I’ve had issues with spd, spd-SL, look keo and delta cleats.
3.  Lube and torque rear derailleur hanger.
4.  Bar and stem and brake lever mounts (for road bike)
5.  Derailleur jockey wheels 
6.  Chainring bolts
7. Then clean and lube chain properly 
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Given that it doesn't do it when coasting and it does when pedalling either in or out of the saddle it's most likely to be the cleats, which can be noisy, or it could be the side of your shoe rubbing against the crank.

If the former then just ignore it. It is considered normal and harmless. If the latter try moving the cleat a bit towards the inside to offset your whole shoe a fraction towards the outside.

Answer (score 0):

If YOU purchased the bike locally, you can bring the bike into the shop where you purchased it and have them service it for you.  Many Trek dealers offer the first tuneup at no charge. It is a proper, thorough wash and tune.  Make certain to tell the service dept about the issue when you drop it off.
Bike shops are also FAR better at diagnosing mysterious creaks.